# Look for consecutive rows based on Hour and grouped by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have a table with hour and dates. I'm trying to look for consecutive hours per date where the 'cnt' column is not equal to 0

For this data:

```
 Date       Hour V1 V2 Cnt
 ---------------------------
 2015-12-15  1   a  b   1
 2015-12-15  2   a  b   2
 2015-12-15  2   b  b   2
 2015-12-15  3   a  b   3
 2015-12-15  3   b  b   2
 2015-12-15  4   a  b   0
 2015-12-15  5   a  b   1
 2015-12-15  6   a  b   1
```

Based on the table above, Date 2015-12-15 has 2 instances where there are consecutive hours where cnt is not equal to 0 (1-3, 5-6)

*Duplicate hours could only happen if V1 and V2 are different*

I'd like to reach this output:

```
 Date       Hour V1 V2 Cnt Cons
 ------------------------------
 2015-12-15  1   a  b   1   3
 2015-12-15  2   a  b   2   3
 2015-12-15  2   b  b   2   1
 2015-12-15  3   a  b   3   3
 2015-12-15  3   b  b   2   1
 2015-12-15  4   a  b   0   0
 2015-12-15  5   a  b   1   2
 2015-12-15  6   a  b   1   2
```

Comment: may I ask why the 4th row's Cnt will become '3' instead of stay the old data as '0'?

Comment: oh sorry, that should also still be 0, will edit it. thanks

Comment: Can there be duplicate hours? E.g. could there be an additional record `2015-12-15/4/a/b/1`? Can there be gaps? E.g. could `2015-12-15/2/a/b/2` be completely missing from the dataset?

Comment: Yes, there can be gaps between hours. There can be a duplicate hour but it will have a different V1 and V2 value

Comment: Okay, but V1, V2 are simply values to show with the records and don't influence anything, right? Could you add duplicate and missing hours to your sample data, so we can see how you want them treated?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited it to show how duplicate hours with different V1, V2 should be treated.

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer. However there is hour 2 and 3 for b-b, shouldn't this be Cons=2 then for these records, as 2 and 3 are consecutive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've edited your question it shows you don't want to look and count in within a day only, but within a day + v1 + v2.

If I select only one v1 / v2 pair for a day except Cnt=0 then I get the corresponding hours to investigate, e.g. 1,2,5,6,8,9. So there can be gaps (real gaps or Cnt=0 gaps), but no duplicates within such a group. If I subtract the position in this result from the values, I get group keys for consecutive hours:

```
hour   pos  hour-pos=groupkey
1      1    1-1=0
2      2    2-2=0
5      3    5-3=2
6      4    6-4=2
8      5    8-5=3
9      6    9-6=3
```

This using I get:

```
select 
  date, hour, v1, v2, 
  count(*) over (partition by date, v1, v2, groupkey) as cons
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*, 
    hour - row_number() over (partition by date, v1, v2 order by hour) as groupkey
  from mytable
  where cnt <> 0
) grouped
union all
select date, hour, v1, v2, 0 as cons
from mytable
where cnt = 0
order by date, hour, v1, v2;
```